# Prevent Page Change in asp.net mvc 5 site with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

i am a little new using mvc5... so,this is my question. How can i prevent a page change(url change) from a menu, or other link, in an asp.net with mvc5 site. I know we can catch the submit method from a button, but how can i do this with a menu option, or when a user changes the url. Can we get browser actions with javascript?

Regards

Comment: something would have to be implemented on the server side to stop me from just manually typing in a url and getting a page. its a direct request to the server so no javascript is ever executed before hitting the server. for menu links, you could intercept the click event and prevent the behavior but this still isnt a safe way to stop it. also all client side access controls should not be trusted as they can be arbitrarily changed so if this is to prevent users from accessing certain things then you 100% absolutely need to be implementing it server side

Comment: Yes, i know i could use somtehing like window.onbeforeunload from the client, but i must implement something in the server side in order to don't call this method every request. So, in other words, the answe is to check in both sides, server and client, isn't it?

Comment: Client side checks would  be for a slightly better user experience (no full page refresh). That's about it